# How to force casting in Java?

Tags: java, casting

I want to force cast a value in Java. For example a boolean into a generic. I checked the type before, so I know what I am doing. But the compiler doesn't want me to cast it. I know that T can be anything. But how can I force the casting?

Example:

```
public <T> T read(T value) {
    if (value instanceof Boolean) {
        return (T) true;
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}
```

ErrorMessage:

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'boolean' to 'T'

---

Old Example:

```
public <T> T read(PersistenceKey key, T defaultValue) {
    if (defaultValue instanceof Boolean) {
        return (T) this.sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key.toString(), (Boolean) defaultValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the full error message.

Comment: Actually I understand clearly your question, I will answer by here because someone decided to close the topic. It's covered in OCA and its called Type Erasure: The compiler use to convert T to Object then perform casting to the type you defined. If you try to cast type T the compile doesn't know what type is T it is yet, so the cast fails.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the reason is that if there is a piece of code where T is *not* Boolean, this will break the code. And that is why the compiler is complaining. It doesn't matter that you are testing defaultValue, because that all comes at runtime, whereas generics are compile time

```
public <T> T read(PersistenceKey key, T defaultValue) {
    if (defaultValue instanceof Boolean) {
        return (T) this.sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key.toString(), (Boolean) defaultValue);
    }
}
```